# Linker error: undefined reference to shared object

Tags: c, compilation, linker, makefile, shared-libraries

I am trying to use an external library called `iniparser` in my C program. I'm using gcc 4.4.

I put the `iniparser` library in a subdirectory called `lib/` header files are in lib/iniparser/src and the library is compiled to `lib/iniparser/libiniparser.so.0`.

I wrote a short Makefile to compile it, here's the output of `make`:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -I include/ src/smag_main.c -L lib/iniparser -liniparser -I lib/iniparser/src
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -I include/ -L lib/iniparser -liniparser -I lib/iniparser/src src/agros.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -I include/ -L lib/iniparser -liniparser -I lib/iniparser/src src/main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -L lib/iniparser -liniparser -o agros smag_main.o main.o agros.o
smag_main.o: In function `sec_haskey':
smag_main.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `iniparser_find_entry'
smag_main.o: In function `parse_config':
smag_main.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `iniparser_load'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `iniparser_getint'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `iniparser_getstring'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `iniparser_getstring'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `iniparser_getstring'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `iniparser_getint'
smag_main.c:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `iniparser_freedict'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [agros] Error 1
```

First call to gcc compiles `smag_main.o` successfully, the second one compiles `agros.o` and the third one `main.o`. The 4th call is the linker, that will link all those objects into an executable `agros`. It obviously fails.

It looks like it has problems locating `iniparser.so` at linking time. How's my call wrong?
I am confused.

(Alternate question, if anyone could explain how to the linking by calling `ld` directly it would be great).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a symlink from `libiniparser.so.0` to `libiniparser.so`

```
 cd lib/iniparser/
 ln -s libiniparser.so.0 libiniparser.so
```

Comment: When you give the command -liniparser the linker is looking for a library with a specific name. Basically libiniparser.a (for a static library) or libiniparser.so (for a shared library). There are reasons to have a file named libiniparser.so.0 For more details see here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html